# How to limit scope of \L& in VIM search replace to apply only to the & and not beyond

Tags: vim

In VIM during search-replace one can use \L& to set the matched string to lower-case, but how do I limit the \L to apply the lower case only to the & (matched string) and not to the rest of the original replace string.

For example:
Original file:

```
ABC
XYZ
```

Expected Result after search-replace:

```
abc Hello There
xyz Hello There
```

I used search-replace like below:

```
%s/.*/\L& Hello There/
```

I am getting this as the result:

```
abc hello there
xyz hello there
```

The "Hello There" should maintain its original case. So is it possible to limit \L to just the word or to set an termination to the \L?

Comment: function way: `%s/.*/\=tolower(submatch(0))." Hello There"` should work too. but Peter's answer is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You end the `\L` with `\E`

```
:%s/.*/\L&\E Hello There/
```

For more help see:

```
:h s/\E
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I didn't know about the existence of \E.

Comment: The help for `\E` is two lines under the help for `\L`.